# What is the best way to create a wizard for web?

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to create a wizard that includes a few steps, that in the final steps 
we need to include all the steps and save to the data base.
What is the best design to do this ?

Is there an implementation for jquery ?
Do I need to save the steps in session till the final save ?

Comment: You could 'fake' a wizard by showing/hiding divs using JavaScript/jquery. However, then you won't have partial submissions in the db, and complicated logic in the wizard is also impossible, i.e. your form fields will always be the same (no branching). That is just a UI trick whereas 'real' wizards often have logic. If you described what you need in more detail, that'd make things easier.

Comment: I like the client side wizard approach too, because the database is only hit once at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not go to the database on each wizard page, then you will have to use either sessions or cookies to store the data between page requests.

You can also use client side tricks that will utilize javascript and hidden frames to hold the data.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a few wizard for www usage. If you need to create 2 or more wizards then it is better to create a simple wizard framework responsible for navigation and data storage in session.

In my case every wizard step implements IWizardStep interface responsible for temporary data storage, as well as some common information like step number, display strings, next & previous steps etc. Then I just put them together and the framework takes care of displaying them in order, navigation and processing.

Comment: You did not answer the question - how to store the interim data to avoid database calls. Sessions? Cookies? something else?

Comment: The first sentence talks about storing data in session - I found this to be the best option, as I can store as much objects as I need to.
Every wizard instance has unique session id because user can have more wizards open at the same time, to avoid data mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that sure if this is what you need but the C# has a wizard control that is a good way to implement wizard type processes.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx

Else, If you want to implement your own flow, use session to capture the values per step and save it later on the last step. cheers..

Comment: concerning the jquery wizard,hope this helps. -http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/260